# How do I link a title with a url in Python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

So im working on a script to download videos for me automatically, however it would seem i have stumbled upon a problem(insufficient experience).

How do i link a category title with a bunch of url's?


**Expected output:**

->CATEGORY 1

->https://example.com/part/of/link/x

->https://example.com/part/of/link/x

->https://example.com/part/of/link/x

.....

->CATEGORY 2

->https://example.com/part/of/link/x

```
for category_title in soup.findAll(class_='section-title'):
    title = category_title.get_text().lstrip()
    print(title)

for onelink in soup.findAll('a'):
    link = onelink.get('href')
    print(f'https://example.com{link}')
```

**What this does is:**

Lists all the titles(10 titles)

Lists all the links(100 links)

```
<div class="section-title">
    CATEGORY 1
    
    <li class="section-item next-random">
        <a class="item" href="/part/of/link/x">

            <div class="title-container">
                <div class="btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">
                    BUTTON
                </div>

                <span class="random-name">
                    URL TITLE
                </span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share website url, from which you try to scrape links and titles? Or html code of this website?

Comment: Ehhh, is it a requirement? Dont really think i am allowed to share it :/ thats like the main reason i left the website out

Comment: @KarolZlot ive added the html code thats needed to see the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the HTML structure of your page is made, you could check the "section-title" parent object, and then, list all the link of that particular section. Giving you all the link for category #

[Here some help](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/beautifulsoup+parent)

Comment: will try this and then get back to you, thanks for sharing